# Opening definition of Emacs command

Tags: emacs

is it possible to open in emacs elisp file with command definition, to see, how it is defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can call `M-x find-function`

Some functions are implemented in C. To be able to find C function you have to download C sources (if you have not yet done so) and add the following line to your .emacs

```
(setq find-function-C-source-directory "/path/to/c-source")
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

`C-h f foo RET` to see the documentation for the function `foo`.

The documentation will tell you, on the first line, where and how the function is defined.  Click the link (or hit `RET` with cursor on it) to the source file where the command is defined. You have to have the Lisp sources (for Lisp code) or the C sources (for C code) installed on your system in order for this to work.

You can also start from a key, without knowing what its command is: `C-h k`.

Comment: `find-function-on-key` is even more direct for starting with a key binding. I bind that to `C-h C-k` (and `find-function` to `C-h C-f`).