# emacs:how can I look for a function with source code?

Tags: emacs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Emacs: how to jump to function definition in .el file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222183/emacs-how-to-jump-to-function-definition-in-el-file)

with C-h f emacs can tell the function document,How can it be function with source code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Emacs: how to jump to function definition in .el file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222183/emacs-how-to-jump-to-function-definition-in-el-file) and [Opening definition of emacs command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103662/opening-definition-of-emacs-command)

Answer (score 0):

When C-h f shows the function documentation then the first line of the help is "... function in " and there is an underlined part. If you switch to the Help window and press Enter or click the middle mouse button on the underlined part then it opens the relevant part of the source code if you have the source files in your Emacs install.

Comment: thanks for that,it works for some ,but I get "The C source file buffer.c is not available" for switch-to-buffer and "function-called-at-point is a compiled Lisp function." for function-called-at-point.